# Why is this electromagnetic field a wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

In D.K.Cheng's *Field and wave electromagnetics* he states the following:

> The phasor electric field intensity for a uniform plane wave propagating in the +$z$-direction is $$\mathbf{E}(z)=E_0e^{-jkz} $$
> where $E_0$ is a constant, $j$ is the imaginary unit and $k$ is the wavenumber.

My question is, why is this a wave? Isn't a wave supposed to be time-dependent? I tried finding the real-notation of the field.
$$\Re(\mathbf{E}(z))=E_0\cos(kz) $$

I get that when $z$ changes the electromagnetic field becomes a cosine function, but can the wavelike behavior also be coordinate dependent. I thought it should be time-dependent?

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Have you read section 7-7.2 (in my edition), "Time-Harmonic Electromagnetics"? - *"Field vectors that vary with space coordinates and are sinusoidal functions of time can similarly be represented by vector phasors that depend on space coordinates but not on time.*" - The key word here is *phasor*.

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time dependent factor, $e^{j\omega t}$ has been omitted, to save clutter. Readers are supposed to supply it for themselves. The omission is usually made only when dealing with waves with the same $\omega$, or with the same wave at different points $z$ in space. In such cases, $e^{j\omega t}$ can be factored out of derivations and put in again at the end, if leaving it out causes worry!

Comment: Can one say: "The electromagnetic field is a wave, because the field magnitude changes like a consine-wave as a function of the $z$-coordinate"?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. There's no indication of a time variation. It's an understood convention to leave out the time factor in the mathematical representation of the wave, but there is no such convention for a verbal explanation.

Answer (score 4):

We hid the time dependence when we said we were using a [*phasor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) representation of the field.

A phasor is a complex number $A$ representing a time dependent quantity $|A|\cos(\omega t+\angle{A})$, where $\omega$ is the previously defined angular frequency at which the instantaneous value of the quantity varies.